# System.loadLibrary() returns exception from static block

Tags: java, static, shared-libraries

I have created a Java app which loads one Windows DLL from the static initialization block.  The code snippet is given below:

```
// MyTestJava class starts
class MyTestJava
{

static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("MyLib");
    }
} // MyTestJava class def ends here
```

I heard that for kinds of library initializations performed from static block, JVM should search in  `java.library.path`. So I set library path for JVM as follows and put `MyLib.dll` under `c:\Libs` folder.

```
options[1].optionString = "-Djava.library.path=C:\\Libs";
```

Unfortunately I'm getting a pesky Unsatisfied Link Error in my Java app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear what `options[1].optionString = "-Djava.library.path=C:\\Libs";` means. You should pass java.library.path as a java arg

```
java -Djava.library.path=C:\Libs MainClass
```

Comment: Sorry. Actually options[1].optionString is given as argument for API JNI_CreateJavaVM() to start JVM from  my C++ program.The other arument am passing to above API is class path.

Answer (score 0):

First call getEnv and check if "java.library.path" actually refers to your library.
Else
You can try giving absolute path of file by using

```
static
{
System.load("C:\\Libs");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rick!.But I can't use absolute path. I also tried System.SetProperty methods to set lib path explicitly. But that also not helped me. Any other way to solve without got for absolute path?

Comment: Did you try getEnv and check whats the value of java.library.path?